# Gulp uglify, rename and sourcemaps

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-rename

I'm trying to do the following in Gulp:
1) Minify JS files from a specified folder to a folder called 'dist'.
2) Append '.min' to the minified filenames.
3) Provide a sourcemap to the minified files and place them in a folder called 'maps'.

I am using 'gulp-uglify', 'gulp-rename' and 'gulp-sourcemaps'.

Here is what I have:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('compress', function () {
    gulp.src('src/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Everything works as intended, except the map files also get '.min' appended to them. How do I restrict the renaming to only occur in the dist folder?

Comment: add this `'!src/*.map'` to `src`  => gulp.src('src/*.js','!src/*.map')

Comment: @matio, the 'src', 'dist', and 'maps' folders are all at the root level. The JS files from 'src' are being extracted into a 'dist' folder properly and the maps folder is being created and the maps file are added. There are no .map files in the 'src' folder for me to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little more digging and found a solution to this.
I ended up breaking the single task into two different ones. Once the files are in the dist folder then I call the 'rename' task. I also used 'vinyl-paths' and 'del' to delete the renamed files. Here is what I have:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var del = require('del');
var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');

gulp.task('compress', ['uglify','rename']);

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('rename', ['uglify'], function() {
    return gulp.src('dist/*.js')
    .pipe(vinylPaths(del))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to combine the two into a single task by leveraging `gulp-rename`'s ability to take a function as input:

```
gulp.task('prod', function() {
    return gulp.src('src.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
            if (!path.extname.endsWith('.map')) {
                path.basename += '.min';
                //gulp-rename with function only concats 'dirname + basename + extname'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/_asset/js'));
});
```

The function basically "only" appends the .min suffix if the file extension name is not .map. The output will be `src.min.js` and `src.js.map`.